# $1/3$ Chance for something to happen whats probability at least $20$ Happen, $21-40$ Happen, $41+$ happen

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

As Title suggests trying to figure how to solve something in excel specifically.

An event has a $1/3$ Chance to occur. 
If I do this $78$ Times whats the chance that:

- It happens $0-20$ Times
- It Happens $21-40$ Times
- It Happens $41-78$ Times

By it happens I mean the $1/3$ event.

Comment: The probability of it happening exactly $k$ times is $(\frac13)^k(\frac23)^{78-k}\binom{78}k$.

Comment: I dont want exactly K times down. 
It needs to be between 0-20 not just a single number

Answer (score 0):

Consider that the probability of it happening exactly $k$ times is $$\left(\frac13\right)^k\left(\frac23\right)^{78-k}\binom{78}k\\=\binom{78}k\left(\frac13\right)^{78}\times2^{78-k}\text.$$

So, the probability of it occuring $0$ to $20$ times is
$$\sum_{k=0}^{20}\binom{78}k\left(\frac13\right)^{78}\times2^{78-k}\\
=\left(\frac13\right)^{78}\sum_{k=0}^{20}\binom{78}k\times2^{78-k}\text.$$

(In Excel, preforming such a summation is simple.)

[image]

The rest is similar (simply change the numbers on the top and bottom of the sigma).

Comment: Any possibility you could assist me in how to write the 0-20 example in excel?

Comment: @Tjay The result should be somewhere near $0.09=9\%$.

Comment: @Tjay Look at the edited answer, I've uploaded a picture.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. 
Quite Surprised the answer is only 9% chance expected it to be more.

Comment: @Tjay The chance for $21-40$ is over $80\%$.